# Как вывести значения из одной и той же таблицы с разницей в один год?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица содержащая дату исследования пациентов.

```
select inspection_date from inspections
```

Исследования пациента происходит не регулярно со случайным промежутком времени.
Нужно вывести в одну строку информацию о первом исследовании и исследование которое было у пациента ближе всего к дате через 1 год.

Comment: покажите структуру таблицы.

Comment: Кроме структуры таблицы покажите образец данных и укажите какой именно у вас диалект SQL

Comment: под вопросом есть ссылка "править", внесите изменения в текст вопроса. И образец данных все таки дайте, что если за год было 5 результатов какой из них подбирать ...